# Shapes.Type....Delete in Excel/PPT VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am trying to delete an existing shape (picture) on a slide and have tried the following, and none of them work. As a bit of background, this code is running in Excel but interacting with powerpoint, and this is just a snippet of the code. Everything else is fine (and PPPres is already defined). I also tried indexing the shape (even though it is the only one on the slide) and using a for loop but still cannot seem to get it to work.

```
 With PPPres.Slides(5).Shapes
    If Shapes.Type = msoPicture Then
       .Delete
    End If
 End With
```

*Error - Method or Data member not found (on .Delete). I know ".Delete" only works in a "with statement" but I have that so I don't know what is wrong. With that said I then tried the following:

```
 If PPPres.Slides(5).Shapes.Type = msoPicture Then
         Shapes.Delete
 End If
```

*Error - Method or Data member not found (on .Type). I know ".Type" exists so I am confused on what the issue is.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapes returns a reference to the entire shapes collection of the slide.
If you're certain there's only one shape, use

```
With PPPres.Slides(5).Shapes(1)
  If .Type = msoPicture Then
    .Delete
  End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am certain there is only one shape, but for the sake of covering my bases I'm going to go with the second answer to make it more robust.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use For Each loop in that case, I think. See below if it helps.

```
For Each shp In PPPres.Slides(5).Shapes
     If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
         shp.Delete
     End If
Next shp
```